# Update Excel from Email based on subject line

Tags: excel, outlook

I want to compare the subject line from Outlook email basically just a six digit number and match the same number with the existing excel column and Mark as completed on a different cell on same row. 
For example if I send email from outlook having the subject 123456 the code should find the column on excel column having number 123456 and automaticaly mark as completed on same row where 123456 exists.
If anyone could help me with the code I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the list of "senders names" for this purpose use this code:
(This code is taken from another post from someone named PatricK)

```
Sub GetFromInbox()
    Const olFolderInbox = 6
    Dim olApp As Object, olNs As Object
    Dim oRootFldr As Object
    Dim lCalcMode As Long

    Dim oItem As Object

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oRootFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) '.Folders("Inbox")

    For Each oItem In oRootFldr.Items
        If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then
            With oItem
                SearchNBR (.SenderName)
                lrow = lrow + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Set oRootFldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Once you have the sender mail, search it on the tab you want and mark it as green!

```
Private Sub SearchNBR(NBR)

    Dim rgFound As Range
    On error resume next
    'Search on the Sheet and range you want!
    Set rgFound = Range("A1:A1000").Find(NBR)

    'It will mark the Sender name in colour green
    rgFound.Interior.Color = vbGreen

End Sub
```

I hope this works for you!!!!
Cheers!

Comment: The sender could be sending other mails which is not pertaining to the sheet, so how can it search the sender plus the subject that includes the 6 digit numbers that will match with the excel sheet and mark as green as mentioned on your code.

Comment: There will be multiple numbers with 6 digits on excel, so how can it pick and match the exact one?

Comment: I get runtime error 91 on rgfound.interior.color= vbgreen?

Comment: That happen when     Set rgFound = Range("A1:A1000").Find(NBR)    not find anything just add On error resume next  just below      Dim rgFound as Range   I just update the code, i hope this works for you!

Comment: But your code does not compare the numbers found on subject line on email. If I put the sender's name on excel it will simply highlight all cells where sender's name is mentioned. I have many numbers with 6 digits and will not compare the subject from email with the number on excel it will just highlight cell where sender's name is updated on cell.